# What is the difference between , and + while concatenating?

Tags: c#

I have been coding with c# for a last couple of months now, but every time I concatenate I always get confused between the difference between the comma `,` and the plus sign `+`. Sometimes `,` works for concatenating, and other times `+` is used. I really don't understand the difference. Please help me out.

Here is the code......

```
class Faculty
{
    string firstName, lastName, address, dateOfBirth, phoneNO, fathersName, mothersName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid first name");

            else
                firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid last name");

            else
                lastName = value;
        }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return this.address; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid adddress");

            else
                address = value;
        }
    }

    public string DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return this.dateOfBirth; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid date of birth");

            else
                dateOfBirth = value;
        }
    }

    public string PhoneNo
    {
        get { return this.phoneNO; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid phone no.");

            else
                phoneNO = value;
        }
    }

    public string FathersName
    {
        get { return this.fathersName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid name");

            else
                fathersName = value;
        }
    }

    public string MothersName
    {
        get { return this.mothersName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new Exception("Enter a valid name");

            else
                mothersName = value;
        }
    }
}

class ExaminationCentre
{
    Dictionary<int, Faculty> dict = new Dictionary<int, Faculty>();
    Faculty counsellor; int id = 100; DateTime yearOfBirth;

    public void AddMembers()
    {
        counsellor = new Faculty(); ;

        Console.Write("Enter your first name: ");
        counsellor.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter your last name: ");
        counsellor.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter your date of birth: ");
        counsellor.DateOfBirth = Console.ReadLine();
        yearOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(counsellor.DateOfBirth);

        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - yearOfBirth.Year;

        Console.Write("Enter your father's name: ");
        counsellor.FathersName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter your mother's name: ");
        counsellor.MothersName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter your phone no: ");
        counsellor.PhoneNo = Console.ReadLine();

        showID();

        dict.Add(id, counsellor);
    }

    void showID()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your id is: " , id++);//but when I'm doing Console.WriteLine("Your id is:"+id++); it isshowing the id.

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExaminationCentre centre;
        Console.WriteLine("Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("1.Add");
        Console.WriteLine("2.Update");
        Console.WriteLine("3.Delete");
        Console.WriteLine("4.Search");
        int select = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (select)
        {
            case 1:
                centre = new ExaminationCentre();
                centre.AddMembers();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry the program is a little incomplete as I am working on it.

Comment: Can you post the code for examples instead of trying to explain the code.

Comment: Can you provide two examples? I am not sure what you mean by "," concatenation. Do you mean string.Format("{0} {1}","bob", "uncle")

Comment: A `,` isn't used for concatenating. Can you show an example of how you think that works?

Comment: We don't want all of the code just the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

The comma is used as a separator while formatting strings, while the plus sign is used for normal concatenation.

Formatting is where you have placeholders such as `{0}` and `{1}`. Other strings, separated by commas, are used to fill these placeholders. Note that the commas are not operators and are simply used to separate parameters. This outputs `Hello world!`:

```
string greet = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", greet, " world!");
```

Concantenation is more straight forward. It simply combines the strings in order. Same example but with concatenation:

```
string greet = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine(greet + " world!");
```

**Edit:** now that you have included the specific problem, here's what you can try:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your id is: {0}" , id++);
```

Comment: I would mention that `,` isn't an operator, it simply separates the parameters to [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is "addition operator". For numbers, it adds them. For dates and timespans, it adds them. For strings (texts) - it joins them, becase there's hardly any other sense of "adding" a text to a text.

Moreover, the `+` is able to "add"/"join"/"concatenate" a non-text to a text, so `"mom" + 5` will actually produce `"mom5"` text. But this is a hack. What it does in this case, is actually:

```
"mom" + (5).ToString()
```

so it calls "ToString()" on the integer 5, gets a string "5" as a result, and adds/joins two texts together. This way it is able to "add" anything to a text - it just "tostring"s everything and joins the strings afterwards.

Now, the second thing:

Commas never work as concatenation. Period.

Commas are for passing parameters to a function/method. `WriteLine` is a method, it takes some parameters. When you call a method by writing `method( )`, you can pass parameters inside `( )`, i.e. `method( 5 )` or `method( "foo" )`. If there would be more than one parameter, then they must be separated by `,` (commas): `method( 5, "foo", "bar")`, and it **does not mean** the 5, foo and bar would be concatenated. They will be passed to the method, and the method will do ... something with them.

It only so happens that the `WriteLine` function may concatenate things. You can read what it exactly does on MSDN or other docs. In short, it takes so-called "format string" and then some extra parameters, and then glues that extra parameters into the "format string" to build a result. For example:

```
format:  Hello {0}!
param1:  Ted
code:    WriteLine("Hello {0}!", "Ted");
result:  Hello Ted!

format:  Hello {0}!
param1:  12.36
code:    WriteLine("Hello {0}!", 12.36);
result:  Hello 12.36!

format:  Hello {0} and {1}!
param1:  John
param2:  Bob
code:    WriteLine("Hello {0} and {1}!", "John", "Bob");
result:  Hello John and Bob!

code:    WriteLine("I ate {0} {1} {2}!", 5, "bad", "bananas");
result:  I ate 5 bad bananas!
```

The {0} {1} etc markers are .. markers. They denote the place where one of the the parameters will be put into. Common name for such marker is "placeholder".

WriteLine writes the text directly to the console. A more useful similar function is `string.Format`. It works the same way: takes a format, some params, builds a result and returns it as a string so you can do something with it other than just dumping it to console.

Check. Consider this, and think how to write it using just "+" without formatstrings:

```
WriteLine("Make me a Foo + {0} bars of {1}", 4 + 2, "goo");
```

spoiler:

```
method: WriteLine
number of params: 3
param1: "Make me a Foo + {0} bars of {1}"   (formatstring)
params: 4 + 2                               (== 6, goes as {0})
param3: "goo"                               (goes as {1})
result: Make me a Foo + 6 bars of goo

alternative way to get such text with extra parens for easier reading:
    ("Make me a Foo + ")  +  (4+2)  +  ("bars of ")  +  ("goo")
```

So, the alternative code would be to take that formula and pass it as a whole to the WriteLine as a one huge parameter -- all in all, the formula produces a ready-to-use text, we need to just display it, no formatting needed:

```
WriteLine( ("Make me a Foo + ")  +  (4+2)  +  ("bars of ")  +  ("goo") );
// or
WriteLine( "Make me a Foo + "  +  (4+2)  +  "bars of "  +  "goo" );
```

it's hard to read, a temporary variable could help a bit:

```
string text = "Make me a Foo + "  +  (4+2)  +  "bars of "  + "goo";
WriteLine( text );
```

That's all just ONE parameter for WriteLine now. No commas needed in such case.

Note the 4+2 must be in parentheses, or else it'd be glued into the string as 4 then 2, not as four-plus-two. Fell free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else told you, the `,` never concatenates. But it is used to pass parameters to functions that do the concatenation.

I got this exact same question from one of my developers ones. After some discussions I realized that he believed that the `,` was concatenating before calling the function, and passing only one string as parameter. 
He though that way simply because he did not know that it is possible to build functions that accepts a variable number of arguments.

Here you can see how I used the `params` keyword to tell C# that should accept a variable number of string arguments. That is what Console.WriteLine() is actually doing

```
 // ConcatenateStrings("multiple", "strings", "are", "passed", "as", "parameters");
 public string ConcatenateStrings(string firstString, params string[] restOfTheStrings)
 {
     // This code is an example only. It is not optimal
     foreach(string oneString in restOfTheStrings)
     {
         firstString += oneString;
     }
     return firstString;
}
```